# Why the bitmapToMat of openCV4Android only support RGBA_8888 and RGB_565?

Tags: opencv, android

I am processing some 16 bit color-png images in Android with OpenCV and convert bitmap to Mat is necessary for me. The bitmap I create is in RGBA_F16 format, but the

```
bitmapToMat
```

only works when bitmap is in ARGB_8888 and RGB_565 format, which can be found in OpenCV source code

```
try {
        LOGD("nBitmapToMat");
        CV_Assert( AndroidBitmap_getInfo(env, bitmap, &info) >= 0 );
        CV_Assert( info.format == ANDROID_BITMAP_FORMAT_RGBA_8888 ||
                   info.format == ANDROID_BITMAP_FORMAT_RGB_565 );
        CV_Assert( AndroidBitmap_lockPixels(env, bitmap, &pixels) >= 0 );
        CV_Assert( pixels );
        dst.create(info.height, info.width, CV_8UC4);
        if( info.format == ANDROID_BITMAP_FORMAT_RGBA_8888 )
        {
            LOGD("nBitmapToMat: RGBA_8888 -> CV_8UC4");
            Mat tmp(info.height, info.width, CV_8UC4, pixels);
            if(needUnPremultiplyAlpha) cvtColor(tmp, dst, COLOR_mRGBA2RGBA);
```

Why the bitmap format is limited to RGBA_8888 and RGB_565, if I simply change

```
Mat tmp(info.height, info.width, CV_8UC4, pixels);
```

to

```
Mat tmp(info.height, info.width, CV_32FC4, pixels);
```

and delete those assertion, then recompile OpenCV, can I make it work? If not, how can I convert the bitmap to mat.

Thanks!